# Where to modify feed status to change number of created and updated nodes

Tags: feeds

i want to change the message after a feed is completed that shows the number updated and created.  What file in the feeds module is the one that outputs this message? using Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha9

the progress is in  feeds.pages.inc
but I still cannot find where  the number created and updated is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in feeds.pages.inc, function feeds_source_status() the status information is shown for the importer, including the number of imported items. The number of items is calculated in FeedsProcessor::itemCount() in plugins/FeedsProcessor.inc.

The message of how many entities were created and updated happens in FeedsProcessor::process(). FeedsSource::$state keeps track of these numbers. The case where these numbers might not be accurate is if the same entity is updated multiple times in a single import. Usually, this is caused by a configuration error: the target that is configured as unique appearantly isn't unique in the source.